# UI5 Tooling command "ui5 serve" does start local server in SAP BAS but why can't I connect to it?

Tags: ui5-tooling, sap-business-application-studio

I have SAP BTP trial account in which Im trying to run a SAPUI5 application via the SAP Business Application Studio (BAS). I have added nothing fancy to it. Just created one from the one of the many UI5 templates and tried running it from the terminal via the command `ui5 serve`.

The command does execute without any problems and also provides me with the standard `localhost:8080` URL. Im using Firefox since BAS doesn't seem to work with Edge as well as Chrome.

[image: Screenshot 1]

I even get a message popping on the right bottom corner telling me a service is listening to port `8080` with a button that says "open in New Tab" pressing it however does nothing.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Im new to SAP BTP and BAS. Are there more things to configure before running the application? Or perhaps I have to configurate the browser itself? The error message:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 1):

I have also had some experience with the Business Application Studio.

You don't work locally here like in VS Code, for example. That's why you can't access it via localhost:8080, but have to use the link that provides the BAS. In this case, something like

port8080-workspaces-....applicationstudio.cloud.sap.

The best thing you can do is to press "Open in new tab" on the screenshot with "A service is listening to port 8080", then you will be redirected to the working link.

Kind regards
Sebastian